# Unable to run JavaScript in IE using Selenium

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-iedriver

I am trying to execute JavaScript from IE using Selenium C#. It's working fine on Firefox and Chrome, but not on IE (version 11).

Below is the sample code which I am trying to run:

```
string script = "document.getElementsByClassName('ITLCover')[0].remove();";
((IJavaScriptExecutor) Driver.WebDriver).ExecuteScript(script);
```

Comment: What do you mean not working?? Is there exception??

Comment: Yes UnexpectedJavaScriptError error.

Comment: Try as `string script = "arguments[0].remove();";
((IJavaScriptExecutor) Driver.WebDriver).ExecuteScript(script, Driver.WebDriver.FindElement(By.ClassName("ITLCover")));` and let me know..

Comment: It works thank you, but the script should use FindElements not FindElement.

          `((IJavaScriptExecutor) Driver.WebDriver).ExecuteScript(script,
               Driver.WebDriver.FindElements(By.ClassName("ITLCover")));`

Comment: No, it would be `FindElement`, `FindElements` returns list of IWebElement while you required single, and I have posted it as an answer need to accept it.. Thanks

Comment: Actually `arguments[0]` means it would takes first argument which you are passing into scripts , it never means it take a list.. follow this link for more details https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_IJavaScriptExecutor_ExecuteScript.htm

Comment: Sorry Saurabh I couldn't accept your answer as I have multiple elements under that className that's why the script given by you will not work .FindElements gives the list of all the elements on that I need element at 0 index arguments[0] represent the same

Comment: NO, `arguments[0]` represents list of IWebElement then..actually `arguments` represent how many agrs you are passing in the `ExecuteScript()`, where first param is javascript and another is list of objects, you basically you are sending something like as `Object[] = {List}`, so in the script `arguemnts[0]` gets the list instead of single Thanks..:)

Comment: SO basically if you are passing list you have to manage your script as `arguments[0][0].remove();` for single element..

Comment: yes true you are correct sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to find element using selenium script and need to paas it as an arguments to [`ExecuteScript()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_IJavaScriptExecutor_ExecuteScript.htm) as below :-

```
string script = "arguments[0].remove();"; 

IWebElement element = Driver.WebDriver.FindElement(By.ClassName("ITLCover"));

((IJavaScriptExecutor) Driver.WebDriver).ExecuteScript(script, element);
```

**Edited** :- If you want to pass list of `IWebElement`, and perform script using `index`, try as :-

```
int index = 0;
string script = "arguments[0][arguments[1]].remove();"; 

((IJavaScriptExecutor) Driver.WebDriver).ExecuteScript(script, Driver.WebDriver.FindElements(By.ClassName("ITLCover")), index);
```